# How to overwrite all login forms in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to override the login form as follows:

```
function my_login_form() {
    $login_type = 'login';
    change_login_form( $login_type );
}
add_action( 'login_form', 'my_login_form' );
```

For that, I use `ob_start()`. However, the default form is output.

```
function change_login_form( $login_type ){

    // Remove default form ( Not going well )
    ob_start();
    ob_clean();
    wp_head(); 

    // Add own form
    $content = html_form( $login_type );

    ob_end_clean();
    echo $content;

}
```

What can I do to override the default form?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom login page that overrides the default WordPress one. There is a section on this page called "Make a Custom Login Page" if you scroll down a bit. [WP Codex : Customizing the Login Form](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form)

You can customize the inputs by passing parameters to the wp_login_form() function in the page-login.php of your theme folder.

```
<?php
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) { // Display WordPress login form:
    $args = array(
        'redirect' => admin_url(), 
        'form_id' => 'loginform-custom',
        'label_username' => __( 'Username custom text' ),
        'label_password' => __( 'Password custom text' ),
        'label_remember' => __( 'Remember Me custom text' ),
        'label_log_in' => __( 'Log In custom text' ),
        'remember' => true
    );
    wp_login_form( $args );
} else { // If logged in:
    wp_loginout( home_url() ); // Display "Log Out" link.
    echo " | ";
    wp_register('', ''); // Display "Site Admin" link.
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you. But I want to add many custom, So I trying In the method using `ob_clean() `.